# how to decide functional responsibilities for SOA services?

Tags: architecture, domain-driven-design, soa, crc-cards

I've been searching (mostly google) to try an find tools or methodologies that I can use to identify the functional responsibilities for SOA services.  My searching hasn't really come up with anything.

Currently, the approach I use for deciding the functional responsibilities is adhoc and is really just gut feel, e.g.

- all customer related functionality goes into a customer service
- all payment related functionality goes into a payment service
- etc

Reflecting on other approaches used in the software design/architecture world:

1. Object Oriented Analysis has the concept of [Class Responsibility Collaboration](http://www.agilemodeling.com/artifacts/crcModel.htm) (CRC) models to decide the responsibility of classes.
2. From what I understand, Domain Driven Design (DDD) has the concept of [bounded contexts](http://www.infoq.com/news/2013/02/ddd-bounded-context-large-domain) to logically partition a domain.
3. In traditional software architecting:

   - the book [Process of Software Architecting](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321357485) has a similar approach to CRC that is used for identifying software components and their responsibilities.
   - the [Architecture Based Design](http://resources.sei.cmu.edu/library/asset-view.cfm?assetid=5147) process has steps for dividing responsibilities info functional areas.

**Question:** What tools/methodologies does the SOA architect have that allow them to determine the functional responsibilities of a service?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your approach and analysis seems reasonable keep a service functionality around the business problem it is trying to resolve. Customer related functionality goes into the customer service etc. However you need to solidify your decision making process and remove the gut feel approach.

What you are referring to is called SOA design time policies part of a larger topic called SOA governance. Remember just having a bunch of web services does not make your architecture SOA rather service based so it is essential that you go through the pain of setting up your SOA Governance before jumping into a SOA architecture. Please note I am making the assumption that this is not in place.

You SOA governance policy will specify how to design your services. A typical SOA design time policy might look something like this around service design.

***Design for reusability.***

When you design a service, it would be nice if this service could be
reused by other services and consumers.

If you look at a SOA system and all of the services  it provides you’ll probably notice that services provide different levels
of granularity. You can have anything from services that allow you to modify a single
property of an entity to services that allow you to apply for a
a loan. Now why is this granularity important? The granularity of a service defines
how easily it can be reused.

Fine-grained services can often be more easily reused than
coarse-grained services. Here is a example of how you can break up this granularity:

- Process services: Process services are the coarsest-grained services. These kinds
  of services most often offer services or products to their consumers. A typical process service example would be something like the sale of a car. In this
  scenario the sales system needs to be updated, the inventory system needs to
  be updated, and a lot more systems are involved in this transaction. A process
  service will call other services to accomplish its task. Typically when you do orchestration between a lot of services you are dealing with a process service
- Business services: A business service provides a single, specific business function
  for a system. For example updating the sales system with the invoice and tax documentation around a sale of a car.
- Technical services: The finest-grained services are the technical services. A technical
  service provides a small piece of specific functionality to other services. An example
  of this would be a service that updates the inventory of cars on the floor i.e. mark the car in the database as sold other example would be to send an email, or call a legacy backend.

You should also keep a catalog of services. This catalog must be kept up to date with the services and their functionality to eliminate duplication of services.It will also allow you to determine where a services functionality must be defined.

Using a catalog of services and design time policies will allow you to decide where functionality should lie.

I would recommend [this book](http://www.manning.com/dirksen/) as it deal with the whole management around SOA. As far as which formal methodology to use I would suggest try them and keep the one that works for you. Keep in mind that it helps to have business people on your decision making team as they understand the business they could probably give you insight into where the functionality should lie. Just formalize it in your SOA governance policies and review those policies every 8-12 months to ensure they are still relevant and are working for you.